# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset if response doesn't receive within 5 minutes

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

`I am getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset while running Jmeter test if the response on the page is exceeding 4 minutes even for the single user. If I run this test (Outside Jmeter) from Browser, it is running file even response is taking 5 minutes.  Please help me to resolve this issue. Error logs for quick reference "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" "at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:313)" "at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:340)" "at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:789)"  "at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:1025)"  "at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)" "at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:477)" "at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)" "at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1461)" "at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1066)" "at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)" "at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)" "at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)" "at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)" "at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)" "at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)" "at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)" "at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)" "at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)" "at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)" "at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)" "at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)" "at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)" "at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)" "at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)" "at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)" "at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:939)" "at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:650)" "at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)" "at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1301)" "at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1290)" "at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)" "at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)" "at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)" "at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)" "at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)"

I have tried multiple options by changing below properties but no luck.
In user.properties file: "http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true", "httpclient4.retrycount=1", "hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters", "httpclient4.time_to_live=600000"

In Jmeter properties file: "https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2", "https.socket.protocols=TLSv1.2", "https.use.cached.ssl.context=true", "server.rmi.ssl.disable=true", "hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters", "http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true", "httpclient4.retrycount=1", "httpclient4.time_to_live=600000"

HTTP Request Defaults: "Implementation = HttpClient4", "Timeouts (milliseconds): Connect: 600000 & Response: 600000"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare the requests from JMeter and from the real browser, this way you will be able to figure out the differences and who's really resetting the connection.

Make sure to [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), it should be sufficient. If you will make the same request including URL, body and [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) as the real browser does - you should get the same behaviour/response.

With regards to your configuration:

1. All amendments need to be done in *user.properties* file, the values there override the values in *jmeter.properties* file and any defaults
2. `http.connection.stalecheck` should go to **hc.parameters** file
3. There is also `httpclient4.idletimeout` property which you may want to play with

Be informed that all these overrides are **workarounds** and should be applied only if you're **absolutely** sure that:

1. Server behaves as expected functionally
2. JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser with 100% accuracy

More information: [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed)